# How to use Faker.js in NPM-based browser project?

Tags: node.js, npm

I use npm as a package manager for my web frontend projects. I have a need to generate some fake data locally within JavaScript in a project. Faker.js seems to be the perfect library to do so.

Most libraries, when I install them with npm, either have usable `js` files at the root of the installed files or provide a `dist` or similar folder with the `.js` files that I can reference, e.g. `<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>` Faker.js however does not include this.

The documentation for faker simply includes this line: `<script src = "faker.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>` Clearly this will not work since the package doesn't even install a file called `faker.js` anywhere. My assumption is that you're expected to either use it with Node.js (non web frontend) projects or you're expected to build it somehow to get the `faker.js` file.

One tutorial I found online says you can `npm install faker` and then use `<script src="node_modules/faker/build/build/faker.js">`. But I also do not have a `build` folder. The tutorial didn't give any instructions on building the `faker.js` file.

Can someone shed some light on how this works? I have actually seen at least one other package (jQuery) that is similar and does not include a compiled usable browser version in the distribution. In past projects I've simply downloaded a compiled .js file and included it in my source control, but I'd like to try to avoid that if at all possible!

(Please don't answer with "just use a CDN" - I am working in an environment with specific policy requirements that HTML on the production server may not directly reference any off-site assets or scripts, but it is OK to pull in those libraries and self-host them. Frustrating, yes, but I don't get to make the rules.)